# To allow only localhost in Apache's 000-default

Tags: apache

**How can you allow only localhost in Apache2?**

*My /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default is*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /home/masi/Dropbox/a
<Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/masi/Dropbox/a/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                deny from all                             // Problem HERE!
        allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I browse to `http://localhost/index.php` unsuccessfully. I get `Forbidden`.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Please, move this question to serverfault to solve the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Switch your allow, deny order around (you want to deny all first, then allow localhost).

Change:

```
Order allow,deny
```

To:

```
Order deny,allow
```

(which is the default behavior)

Comment: This is correct. However, in my case (using macos x Mountain Lion) I also had to allow the ipv6 localhost address, that is I added the following additonal line: Allow from fe80::1

Comment: Starting with Apache 2.4, you can now just write [`Require local`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html) instead

Answer (score 12):

More simple. Look at the "/usr/share/doc" configuration :) copy & paste!

```
 <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Reply to Maha's answer**

This is the file which works for me. You can have what you want in the place of /var/www.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                deny from all
        allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

If wanting to configure multiple virtual hosts, some allowed access from outside of localhost and some not, then the method in the original question works when the fixes from other answers on this page are followed.

However, if the desire is to only ever allow localhost, then changing the `Listen` and `ServerName` at the top-level configuration will do it. So might blocking the port in the system's firewall.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
ServerName localhost:80
```

*I think demonstrating an example of configuring a firewall is outside of the scope here since there are many different firewalls that could be in use.*

Comment: Thanks - thie OP's question was broadly about apache, in general, but most answers focused on that particular vhost or provided their own. This is the most elegant and proper answer for those coming by for the broad answer.